# Spawning items at sides of a spline

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just done the Curves and Splines Tutorials from the catlikecoding.com website (http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/) and after finishing it I came up with an idea. I would like to spawn the items from the SplineDecorator at the same distance from the spline at both sides of the spline. I have tried duplicating the for loop and instantiating the newItem twice but at different position but it doenst work as I want to. Here's the Spline Decorator script that takes a spline and then Instantiate some items along the its path

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SplineDecorator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BezierSpline spline;
    public int frequency;
    public float distanceBetweenItems;
    public bool lookForward;
    public Transform[] items;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (frequency <= 0 || items == null || items.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        float stepSize = 1f / (frequency * items.Length);

        for (int p = 0, f = 0; f < frequency; f++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++, p++)
            {
                Transform item = Instantiate(items[i]) as Transform;
                Vector3 position = spline.GetPoint(p * stepSize);

                item.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(position.x + distanceBetweenItems, position.y, position.z);

                if (lookForward)
                {
                    item.transform.LookAt(position + spline.GetDirection(p * stepSize));
                }

                item.transform.parent = transform;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define exactly what "at both sides" means to you, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe this will get you on the right track.

I replaced the inner loop with the following and got a sort of "race track" feel with `distanceBetweenItems = 2`:

```
Transform item  = Instantiate(items[i]) as Transform;
Transform item2 = Instantiate(items[i]) as Transform;

Vector3 position  = spline.GetPoint(p * stepSize);
Vector3 direction = spline.GetDirection(p * stepSize);
Vector3 cross     = Vector3.Cross(direction, Vector3.up);
Vector3 delta     = cross.normalized * (distanceBetweenItems/2);

item.transform.localPosition  = new Vector3(position.x + delta.x, position.y + delta.y, position.z + delta.z);
item2.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(position.x - delta.x, position.y - delta.y, position.z - delta.z);

if (lookForward)
{
    item.transform.LookAt( position + spline.GetDirection(p * stepSize));
    item2.transform.LookAt(position + spline.GetDirection(p * stepSize));
}

item.transform.parent  = transform;
item2.transform.parent = transform;
```

What I've done here is use Vector3.Cross() [(Unity Documentation)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) to find the line perpendicular to both the spline and `Vector3.up`. Then I calculate how far along that line to go by normalizing it and multiplying it by half of `distanceBetweenItems`. (So that, combined, they're `distanceBetweenItems` apart.)

If you instead wanted something like tracing the wingtips of a plane flying that spline, you'll need to replace the `Vector.up` above. The simplest way is to replace it with the 'binormal vector', though there are issues with that. [This pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~462/projects/assn2/assn2/cameraMovement.pdf) I just found talks a little about it, and might get you on the right path.

(Goofing around, I was able to get a reasonable approximation by replacing the `Vector3 cross = ...` line with `Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(direction, direction - spline.GetDirection(p * stepSize + 0.01f));`, though it's screwy on sharp bends, non-mirrored vertices, and at the start/end loop.)